# visual editor not working in wordpress 4.0

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the circle theme and just want to know whether visual Editor actually not working.visual editor shows blank page.and text is not showing in front end if i am write in text editor.

Would really appreciate your help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are work arounds for this:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/visual-editor-not-working-after-upgrade-to-40

It is always good to reinstall it :)

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if

```
\wp-includes\js\tinymce\plugins\wpgallery\plugin.min.js
```

is actually installed.

Check to see if you can open this in your browser

```
http://<yoursite>/wp-includes/js/tinymce/wp-tinymce.php
```

Make sure you have JavaScript enabled.

Also, check your .htaccess and look to see if anything unusual is blocking it.